# Start a process in a user session on Windows from an OpenSSH session

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm trying to start a process in the interactive session of the currently logged-on user using Win32 API. The start-up is taking place from a remote SSH session, so this should be similar to starting a process in an interactive session from a service. The remote SSH session is logged-in with the same user that I'm trying to start-up a process in the interactive session for.

I have the following setup:

- A Windows Server 2019 GCE VM
- OpenSSH server is enabled on the server machine
- A user administrator that has the following privileges:

  - Act as the operating system administrator
  - Impersonate a client after authentication

I use the following piece of C# code to start-up the process, in this case it's notepad.exe. The code is opening the token of `explorer.exe` process which should run in the user session. The token is then duplicated and used to create the process.

```
var pHandle = OpenProcess(
  0x001F0FFF, 
  false, 
  explorerPID);

if (pHandle == IntPtr.Zero) { // handle win32 error }

if (!OpenProcessToken(pHandle, 
  TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, 
  out IntPtr tHandle)) {
    // handle win32 error
}

var lpT = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
if (!DuplicateTokenEx(
        tHandle, 
        TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, 
        ref lpT, 
        SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation,
        TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary,
        out IntPtr newtHandle)) { 
    // handle win32 error
}

var startInfo = new STARTUPINFO();
var lpProcAttr = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
var lpThreadAttr = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
startInfo.lpDesktop = "winsta0\\default";
startInfo.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(startInfo);
if (!CreateProcessAsUser(newtHandle, 
       "c:\\Windows\\notepad.exe",
       null,
       ref lpProcAttr,
       ref lpThreadAttr,
       false,
       0x00000020,
       IntPtr.Zero,
       null,
       ref startInfo,
       out _)) {
    // handle win32 error
}
```

I am deploying the binary on the server and then via SSH I'm executing it. The problem is I'm getting `(5) Access is denied` on the `CreateProcessAsUser` function. Does anyone have any clue of what I'm missing here or if it's even possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

for call `CreateProcessAsUser` in general case you need `SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME` privilege. also you can search for some process in some session (like explorer) and use it token. or you can enumerate terminal sessions and get token from session. for this you need TCB privilege. both this possible got you you initially have Debug privileges. code can be next:

```
#define BEGIN_PRIVILEGES(name, n) static const union { TOKEN_PRIVILEGES name;\
struct { ULONG PrivilegeCount; LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES Privileges[n];} label(_) = { n, {

#define LAA(se) {{se}, SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED }
#define LAA_D(se) {{se} }

#define END_PRIVILEGES }};};

const SECURITY_QUALITY_OF_SERVICE sqos = {
    sizeof (sqos), SecurityImpersonation, SECURITY_DYNAMIC_TRACKING, FALSE
};

const OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa_sqos = { sizeof(oa_sqos), 0, 0, 0, 0, const_cast<SECURITY_QUALITY_OF_SERVICE*>(&sqos) };

const TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp_Debug = { 1, { { { SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE }, SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED } } };

BEGIN_PRIVILEGES(tp_TCB, 3)
    LAA(SE_TCB_PRIVILEGE),
    LAA(SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_PRIVILEGE),
    LAA(SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_PRIVILEGE),
END_PRIVILEGES

NTSTATUS GetToken(PVOID buf, const TOKEN_PRIVILEGES* RequiredSet)
{
    NTSTATUS status;

    union {
        PVOID pv;
        PBYTE pb;
        PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION pspi;
    };

    pv = buf;
    ULONG NextEntryOffset = 0;

    do 
    {
        pb += NextEntryOffset;

        HANDLE hProcess, hToken, hNewToken;

        CLIENT_ID ClientId = { pspi->UniqueProcessId };

        if (ClientId.UniqueProcess)
        {
            if (0 <= NtOpenProcess(&hProcess, PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, 
                const_cast<POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES>(&oa_sqos), &ClientId))
            {
                status = NtOpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_DUPLICATE, &hToken);

                NtClose(hProcess);

                if (0 <= status)
                {
                    status = NtDuplicateToken(hToken, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES|TOKEN_IMPERSONATE, 
                        const_cast<POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES>(&oa_sqos), FALSE, TokenImpersonation, &hNewToken);

                    NtClose(hToken);

                    if (0 <= status)
                    {
                        status = NtAdjustPrivilegesToken(hNewToken, FALSE, const_cast<PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES>(RequiredSet), 0, 0, 0);

                        if (STATUS_SUCCESS == status)   
                        {
                            status = NtSetInformationThread(NtCurrentThread(), ThreadImpersonationToken, &hNewToken, sizeof(hNewToken));
                        }

                        NtClose(hNewToken);

                        if (STATUS_SUCCESS == status)
                        {
                            return STATUS_SUCCESS;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } while (NextEntryOffset = pspi->NextEntryOffset);

    return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
}

NTSTATUS AdjustPrivileges(_In_ const TOKEN_PRIVILEGES* ptp)
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    HANDLE hToken, hNewToken;

    if (0 <= (status = NtOpenProcessToken(NtCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_DUPLICATE, &hToken)))
    {
        status = NtDuplicateToken(hToken, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES|TOKEN_IMPERSONATE, 
            const_cast<OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES*>(&oa_sqos), FALSE, TokenImpersonation, &hNewToken);

        NtClose(hToken);

        if (0 <= status)
        {
            if (STATUS_SUCCESS == (status = NtAdjustPrivilegesToken(hNewToken, FALSE, 
                const_cast<PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES>(ptp), 0, 0, 0)))
            {
                status = NtSetInformationThread(NtCurrentThread(), ThreadImpersonationToken, &hNewToken, sizeof(hNewToken));
            }

            NtClose(hNewToken);
        }
    }

    return status;
}

NTSTATUS ImpersonateToken(_In_ const TOKEN_PRIVILEGES* RequiredSet)
{
    NTSTATUS status = AdjustPrivileges(&tp_Debug);

    ULONG cb = 0x40000;

    do 
    {
        status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;

        if (PBYTE buf = new BYTE[cb += PAGE_SIZE])
        {
            if (0 <= (status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, buf, cb, &cb)))
            {
                status = GetToken(buf, RequiredSet);

                if (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
                {
                    status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
                }
            }

            delete [] buf;
        }

    } while(status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH);

    return status;
}
    
void StartNotepadInSession(ULONG dwSessionId)
{
    HANDLE hToken;
    WCHAR sz[MAX_PATH];

    if (SearchPathW(0, L"notepad.exe", 0, _countof(sz), sz, 0))
    {
        if (WTSQueryUserToken(dwSessionId, &hToken))
        {
            PVOID lpEnvironment;
            if (CreateEnvironmentBlock(&lpEnvironment, hToken, FALSE))
            {
                PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
                STARTUPINFOW si = { sizeof(si) };

                if (CreateProcessAsUserW(hToken, sz, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT, lpEnvironment, 0, &si, &pi))
                {
                    NtClose(pi.hThread);
                    NtClose(pi.hProcess);
                }
                DestroyEnvironmentBlock(lpEnvironment);
            }
            NtClose(hToken);
        }
    }
}

void exec()
{
    if (0 <= ImpersonateToken(&tp_TCB))
    {    
        ULONG MySessionId, SessionId;
        ProcessIdToSessionId(GetCurrentProcessId(), &MySessionId);

        PWTS_SESSION_INFOW pSessionInfo;
        ULONG Count;
        if (WTSEnumerateSessionsW(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, 0, 1, &pSessionInfo, &Count))
        {
            DbgPrint("Sessions = %x\r\n", Count);
            if (Count)
            {
                pSessionInfo += Count;
                do 
                {
                    --pSessionInfo;

                    DbgPrint("SESSION_INFO<%x>: %x %S\r\n", pSessionInfo->SessionId, pSessionInfo->State, pSessionInfo->pWinStationName);

                    if (SessionId = pSessionInfo->SessionId)
                    {
                        switch (pSessionInfo->State)
                        {
                        case WTSDisconnected:
                        case WTSActive:
                            if (MySessionId != SessionId)
                            {
                                StartNotepadInSession(SessionId);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                } while (--Count);
            }

            WTSFreeMemory(pSessionInfo);
        }

        RevertToSelf();
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Does this mean you can effectively use an Admin token?!